# composer update segmentation fault if too many packages

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a project on a Homestead vagrant box on Mac OS 10.9.2. When I do `composer update` I get a `segmentation fault (core dumped)` error if I have more than 6 packages required. Doesn't matter which packages they are, composer can't get past the `Updating dependencies (including require-dev)` stage before crashing.

There is no actual core dump file generated that I can tell.

I tried running `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install php5` to get the latest PHP 5.6.5 (updated from 5.6.0) to see if this was potentially a bug in PHP itself, but that didn't resolve the issue.

What could be the likely culprit here?

Comment: Can you run composer with `-v` argument to look for any informations.